# Chrome crashes after GetUserMedia

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

Every attempt to run WebRTC with Google Chrome results in a crash after GetUserMedia has been accepted for video. Chrome stops responding and Windows reports:

> Unhandled exception 0x7791EA5F (ntdll.dll) in chrome.exe: 0xC0000374: En heap har blitt skadet (parameters: 0x77954270)

Example https://apprtc.appspot.com

I seem to be lost solving this as Firefox runs fine on the same machine (Windows 7). I have have reinstalled Chrome, but the error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

file a crash report from chrome://crashes -- this will usually get fixed pretty quickly, even more so if you add "webrtc" to the issue title.

Comment: Have already done that, but I am not sure I'll hear anything from them. Chrome just stops responding but does not generate a crash report 

Martin

Answer (score 0):

Switching to the latest Chrome beta version solved the problem :)